# Visualisation of clusters using outer coordinates of the individual cluster

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, k-means, graph-visualization

I want to visualise my clusters.

By using this code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

X = np.array([[28, 7], [36, 5], [32, 2], [56, 8], [47, 5], [50,100], [100,100], [26,59], [19,71],
              [75, 9], [34, 4], [56, 9], [28, 1], [33, 6]])
col = ['blue', 'green', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k', "violet", "indigo"]
ncluster = 2
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=ncluster, max_iter=500).fit(X)
y = kmeans.labels_
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
clusters_centroids = dict()
clusters_radii = dict()
for cluster in range(ncluster):
    clusters_centroids[cluster] = list(
        zip(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1]))[cluster]
    clusters_radii[cluster] = max([np.linalg.norm(np.subtract(
        i, clusters_centroids[cluster])) for i in zip(X[y == cluster, 0], X[y == cluster, 1])])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(7, 5))

def drawclusters():
    for i in range(ncluster):
        plt.scatter(X[y == i, 0], X[y == i, 1], s=100,
                    c=col[i], label=f'Cluster {i + 1}')
        art = mpatches.Circle(
            clusters_centroids[i], clusters_radii[i], edgecolor=col[i], fill=False)
        ax.add_patch(art)
    plt.scatter(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1], s=200,
                c='red', label='Centroids', marker='x')


drawclusters()
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I am getting circles:

[image: circular visualisation]

But I want to visualise using points something similar to this *ignore the data part I just need the visualisation part* ( I need shapes ):

[image: non ciruclar]

I need code in python. There is a function **fviz_cluster**  in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the convex hull of each of the clusters using `scipy.spatial.ConvexHull()`. Note that `X[y == i]` needs to be converted to a new array, because `ConvexHull()` returns indices into the short array. The returned points form a polygon. The first point needs to be copied at the end to plot to include the line segment that closes the polygon.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull

def drawclusters(ax):
    for i in range(ncluster):
        points = X[y == i]
        ax.scatter(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], s=100, c=col[i], label=f'Cluster {i + 1}')
        hull = ConvexHull(points)
        vert = np.append(hull.vertices, hull.vertices[0])  # close the polygon by appending the first point at the end
        ax.plot(points[vert, 0], points[vert, 1], '--', c=col[i])
        ax.fill(points[vert, 0], points[vert, 1], c=col[i], alpha=0.2)
    ax.scatter(centroids[:, 0], centroids[:, 1], s=200, c='red', label='Centroids', marker='x')

X = np.array([[28, 7], [36, 5], [32, 2], [56, 8], [47, 5], [50, 100], [100, 100], [26, 59], [19, 71],
              [75, 9], [34, 4], [56, 9], [28, 1], [33, 6]])
col = ['blue', 'green']
ncluster = 2
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=ncluster, max_iter=500).fit(X)
y = kmeans.labels_
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(7, 5))
drawclusters(ax)
ax.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]